# there is a problem with the relationship between '\0' and string.length()

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s = "AA";
    cout << s.length() <<"    "<< s << endl;
    s[1] = '\0';
    s[0] = '\0';
    cout << s.length() <<"    "<< s << endl;
    string w = "\0";
    cout << w.length() <<"    "<< w << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
2    AA
2
0
```

why the second output is 2 instead of 0?
I tried to find the answer on the Internet but couldn't find it.
Can someone answer me？

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C++11 it is guaranteed that a `std::string` is null-terminated, but adding any `\0` char to a string does not change its length.

In C++, a string can contain a `\0` char because its length is solely defined by the size stored in the object and not by the occurrence of any `\0` char within the string.

You need to resize the string manually if you want a `\0` char anywhere in the string to affect its length:

```
s.resize(strlen(s.c_str()))
```

But, if you already know where you place the `\0` char then you should use `s.resize()` right from the beginning to resize the string instead of placing a `\0` char.

Comment: @joebrave writing in **bold** should only be used to **highlight** certain parts of the text. Don't use that as a default, neither in the comment nor in the answer nor in the question or answer section.

Comment: Thank you for your correction. I am new to this site and my English is not good. I am sorry for using the wrong format.

Comment: @joebrave a bad english - as long as it is somehow understandable - is not a problem. But not writing  **everything in bold** (or EVERYTHING IN UPPERCASE) is a rule that applies anywhere not only here on StackOverflow.

Comment: yeah, i will remember this.